# empty json from google maps api url fetch

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am using google maps API to get a city name from coordinates. When I fetch the API url I get an empty json

```
unction callWCoords(position) {
    let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    let longitude =position.coords.longitude;
    let call1;
    let API1="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=+"+latitude+","+longitude+"&key=AIzaSyAfH3Ypu0Al8HpNRXhOPEzGLeNbkxOlsoI"
    fetch(API1).then(
        response=>{alert(JSON.stringify(response));

        }).then( data=>{

    })
    //getPlaceC(call1);

}
```

`JSON.stringfy(response)` returns `"{}"` as well if I try `JSON.stringfy(data)` in the second .then block. Since in the official google json I should get an array called `results` I tried to substitute `results` with `data` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
function callWCoords(position) {
    let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    let longitude =position.coords.longitude;
    let API1="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=+"+latitude+","+longitude+"&key=AIzaSyAfH3Ypu0Al8HpNRXhOPEzGLeNbkxOlsoI"
    fetch(API1).then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
}
```

You must call the res.json() function on the fetch return to get the data.
Also, you are not returning the data back after alert, which is basically removing the data from the next `.then`

Comment: I hadn't nested it, I had put it inside the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` to test it locally.